# Changing the font size on the address fields in the Letter document class

Tags: fontsize, letters

I'm trying to create a letter using the default letter document class. In the name, address, and telephone fields, I want the font to be styled differently than the rest of the document, but I can't seem to get it right. Here's a MWE detailing what I'm doing.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}

\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics{image.jpg}}

\headsep=1.25in 

\longindentation=2.9in

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{\textsc{VIA COURIER} \bigskip \\Mr. Buck Mulligan\\Associate\\K=Attorneys R Us\\29 Lawyer Way\\Edgewater, NJ 07020} 
\name{Joy James\\Associate}
\signature{Joy James\\Associate}
\address{Joy James\\Associate\\Direct Dial: (212) 555-5555\\Direct Fax: (212) 555-2222\\jjames@awesomelaw.com} 
\telephone{(212) 555-5555}
\opening{Dear Buck,}
```

Can anyone help me figure out to style these address entries? If I do something like:

```
\address{\small{The address}}
```

it gives me warnings when I run pdflatex and doesn't render correctly.

Comment: You should use `\address{{\small The address}}`. Other than that, regular font adjustments to any of the fields return the expected results.

Answer (score 3):

The following works in terms of font-modification for the `\address` field:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}

\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
%\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics{image.jpg}}

\headsep=1.25in 

\longindentation=2.9in

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{\textsc{VIA COURIER} \bigskip \\Mr. Buck Mulligan\\Associate\\K=Attorneys R Us\\29 Lawyer Way\\Edgewater, NJ 07020} 
\name{Joy James\\Associate}
\signature{Joy James\\Associate}
\address{{\Large Joy James}\\%
  {\large Associate}\\%
  {\small Direct Dial: (212) 555-5555}\\%
  {\Huge Direct Fax: (212) 555-2222}\\%
  {\tiny jjames@awesomelaw.com}} 
\telephone{(212) 555-5555}
\opening{Dear Buck,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers work, but  I find this hack easier for making the addresses larger/smaller than the main text.

Make the document font small,

> \documentclass[10pt]{letter}

but from the opening onwards, increase the font size,

> \opening{\large Dear Sir,}

Now everything before the opening is smaller than the main body.